# PHP library for parsing mysql create queries and getting difference with exists tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-parser

I search PHP library that gets "CREATE TABLE" query and returns difference if this table already exists
For example I have table "table1"

```
id (int11) | name (varchar64)
----------------------------
```

Then I parse query:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 id int(11), name varchar(255), description text
```

And parser returns 2 queries:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 CHANGE name name varchar(255)
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD description text
```

Can you advise me php library that can do it?

Comment: You can do this yourself too very easily. You wouldn't need to have a big API for that. Try to look into functionalities like `DESCRIBE` `EXPLAIN` etc. You can then match the *creation* vs the *alteration* that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [Doctrine Migrations](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations) or one of the other scads of migrations libraries.

Google for *php migrations library*.